# Minifying jQuery plugin scripts?

Tags: jquery, minify

I am using two or three jQuery plugins on my web page and I have located the source of these plugins but there is no minified version available. Due to licensing and any other rules I have to follow, am I allowed to run this code through a jQuery minify tool (JsMini.com to be specific) to shrink the file size down?

Comment: what happened when you run there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the license that is used. You will find the license in the top of the JS file. If the license permits modifying the file contents, then you are allowed to minify.

Most people use the MIT license. If that is the case, you can minify the JS and add the license text to the top of the minified file version, because, the MIT license permits modifying the source but requires that you have a copy of the license text.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it should be OK to minify a source, but you should check the individual licenses of the plugins. If you are using jQuery itself, then minifying it is OK.

Usually, you might need to include a header comment with the license, so you might need to preserve comments.